# jquery nicescroll: mouse wheel issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

On chrome and when the page direction is 'rtl', the page cannot be scrolled when the mouse wheel is scrolled forwards, page scrolls only when the mouse wheel is scrolled backwards. you may find the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k3tu16eh/).

```
$(function () {
    $('header').niceScroll();
})
```

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/k3tu16eh/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try using [jQuery Mousewheel plugin.](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/mousewheel.html)

```
$(function() {

   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });
```

Comment: thanks stanze. the problem is I am working on an existing project and we are worried that we will lose the customization of scrollbar provided by nicescroll.